# How to send a notification without waking the screen on Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a foreground service in my app, whose persistent notification has a timer in it, which means that the notification is sent once per second to update the timer that is shown in the notification.  This means that on some devices, where notifications are set to either wake the screen entirely or show a dark version on the screen briefly, the screen is constantly awake.

Is there a way to send the notification in a way that it won't wake up the screen?  Setting it as a silent notification on the device fixes this, but the point of a foreground service notification is that it's prominent on the device, so this isn't a great solution, and not all users would know to do that.

This is how I'm building the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Currently Reading")
            .setSound(null)
            .setContentIntent(TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
                addNextIntentWithParentStack(timerIntent)
                getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )
            })
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
```

Comment: I think there is a `setShowSilent` or `setSilent` you can use... But am not even sure if it would not wake up the device :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried updating the notification instead? And use setOnlyAlertOnce()

"You can optionally call setOnlyAlertOnce() so your notification interupts the user (with sound, vibration, or visual clues) only the first time the notification appears and not for later updates."

Check this link
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#Updating

Answer (score -1):

> setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)?

lower it, so wont be shown on lockscreen (android 7 and up)

and here we go with a small fix for **this** part:
`setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)`

you can also add:
`setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)`

but it'll also remove notification from lockscreen...

docs:

1. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#lockscreenNotification
2. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#importance

hope this helps =]

Comment: also this can be useful -» https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#CATEGORY_SERVICE =]